# how to use share_ptr for self-define ros message

Tags: ros, rosmessage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to define a share_ptr for a self-defined ros message in one node for zero copy process. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227271/how-to-use-share_ptr-for-self-define-ros-message/) by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2016-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not get your question. What is your problem exactly? Why you are not able to achieve it? shared pointer definitions are automatically created for every message type, even custom ones.

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2016-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on 2016-02-22**:
thanks for your help. could you give me some link about **shared pointer definitions** which as you said will be created automatically. i couldn't find, appreciated.

**Comment by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on 2016-03-06**:
thx for @Javier, his comments is correct.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-07**:
@crazymumu: please accept the answer by @Javier V. Gómez.